# nginx naxsi error - could not build the wlr_url_hash

Tags: nginx, web-application-firewall

I am getting this error in an nginx server compiled in with naxsi

nginx: [emerg] could not build the wlr_url_hash, you should increase wlr_url_hash_bucket_size: 512
nginx: [emerg] $URL hashtable init failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87
nginx: [emerg] WhiteList Hash building failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

wlr_url_hash or wlr_url_hash_bucket_size doesnt seem to be a valid nginx directive in http,server or location blocks

How to increase wlr_url_hash_bucket_size ?